# Matlab plot plane and normal vectors to it

Tags: matlab, vector, equation, normals, plane

I am working with visualization module for my program and currently I am trying to plot a plane and a few normal vectors to it. The problem is in visualization my vectors are not normal to the plane.

create a mesh

```
step = 1/3;
xp = -5 : step : 5;
yp = -5 : step : 5;
[x,y] = meshgrid(xp,yp);
```

plane equation ax+by+cz+d=0;
plane parameters [a b c d]

```
pl = [1 1 1 1]'; 
z = -pl(1)/pl(3)*x - pl(2)/pl(3)*y - pl(4)/pl(3);
```

normal vectors. firsly, their start coordinates.

```
vectorsNum = 3;
xr = randi([-5,5],vectorsNum,1);
yr = randi([-5,5],vectorsNum,1);
zr = -plr(1)/plr(3)*xr - plr(2)/plr(3)*yr - plr(4)/plr(3);
```

then, their directions.

```
nx = repmat(plr(1), vectorsNum, 1);
ny = repmat(plr(2), vectorsNum, 1);
nz = repmat(plr(3), vectorsNum, 1);
```

plotting

```
figure
hold on
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
zlabel('Z');
lim = 7; %limit
axis([-lim lim -lim lim -lim lim]);

mesh(x,y,z)

quiver3(xr,yr,zr,nx,ny,nz,'ob','LineWidth',1)

hold off
```

[image: Normal vectors to the plane]

We see on the figure that our 'normals' are not normal to the plane

Comment: They are normal to the plane. Try `axis equal`

Comment: ah! it worked! I have used 
`lim = 7`
`axis([-lim lim -lim lim -lim lim])`
but it didn't work

Comment: it seems that your axes unit lengths are not equal. do [`axis equal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#inputarg_style)